# Kubernetes: How to delete PODs based on age/creation time

Tags: minikube, kubernetes

Is it possible to delete POD in kubernetes based on creation time or age?

Example : I would like to delete all PODs which are older than 1 day. These PODs are orphaned , therefore no new PODs will be created.

Answer (score 60):

This command will delete all PODs older than one day :

```
kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}} {{.metadata.creationTimestamp}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | awk '$2 <= "'$(date -d 'yesterday' -Ins --utc | sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" { print $1 }' | xargs --no-run-if-empty kubectl delete pod
```

This command will delete all PODs older than 4 hours :

```
kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}} {{.metadata.creationTimestamp}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | awk '$2 <= "'$(date -d'now-4 hours' -Ins --utc | sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" { print $1 }' | xargs --no-run-if-empty kubectl delete pod
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A couple of observations: First of all, this needs GNU `date`, so if for example you're running this inside an alpine container it will fail unless you install that version of `date`. My version of kubectl was outputting `+00:00` instead of `+0000`. Also, nanoseconds don't seem to be necessary.

Comment: The above command requires GNU version of xargs and date, which can be installed on macOS from HomeBrew as gxargs and gdate respectively.

`brew install findutils coreutils`

Comment: Thanks for this snippet! Super helpful :)

Comment: can anybody explain how this comparison is working/valid `$2 <= "'$(date -d 'yesterday' -Ins --utc `  ?

Comment: I like this solution a lot but it looks like the `date -d 'yesterday' -Ins --utc` part does not work on macOS sadly, probably because macOS is BSD based but the answer is for standard GNU. Anyone have a solution for macOS?

Comment: @MichaelButler See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66479725/8431936) below by SQLesion. The main thing is to use `gdate` on macOS which is the GNU version of `date`.

Comment: In my view there is a slight ambiguity with the aforementioned solution in. Since it only uses the age of the pod (calculated using its `CreationTimestamp`) you might end up deleting a pod that was already restarted, say an hour ago, but has an overall age of a day or 4 hours.

Answer (score 32):

We could do this with `awk` by doing a regex `[0-9]+d` directly on the `AGE` ($5, 5th column) column and then printing the corresponding `NAME` ($1, first column) column

```
kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pod | awk 'match($5,/[0-9]+d/) {print $1}')
```

Test first to see what's matching:

```
kubectl get pod | awk 'match($5,/[0-9]+d/) {print $0}'
```

`$0` means all columns

Comment: For me on kubectl 1.18.15 the right column to use is `$4` not `$5`. The spirit of the answer is correct though and I'm hesitant to edit it in case it's my fault, not the answer's

Comment: Any idea on how to do this in powershell?

Comment: I'm sure this is straightforward to most, but don't forget to use namespaces on both the "delete" and "get" statements if you use them.

Comment: Since the separator for the `match()` function seems to be an empty space if your pods have been restarted the column will not match. For example in `<POD_NAME>                               1/1     Running             1 (1h11m ago)   2d` the `AGE` column is the `$7`, while for the rest of the pods (i.e. those without restarts) it is still column `$5` (or `$4` or whatever, depending on the version as mentioned by @2rs2ts)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative answer that uses `kubectl`, `jq`, and `xargs`.

It works locally for me on Mac, but I also uses it in a Kubernetes cronjob that runs debian-slim, so I think it works on both Mac and Linux.

The time is set in seconds (86400s here for 1 day).

```
kubectl get pod -o json | jq -r --argjson timestamp 86400 '.items[] | select (.metadata.creationTimestamp | sub("\\..*";"Z") | sub("\\s";"T") | fromdate < now - $timestamp).metadata.name' | xargs -r -L1 kubectl delete pod ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either add a [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) to track how long the pod alive and kill it when it's longer a certain period. Or you can schedule a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)

Comment: For liveness probe, you can add `/bin/sh -c "touch /tmp/healthy; sleep [time you want the container to alive]; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600"` in the args. I will kill the old container and restart a new one when the time reaches.

Comment: hi Cindy , First of all thank you for the answer, you suggestion is working but it looks like kubectl restarts a container and not deleting a POD.

Comment: I found it easiset to actually run the script from [dansl1982's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48960060/121660) inside a cron job like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908449/121660)

Answer (score 3):

modified to work on mac:

```
# try the gnu versions: gxargs
brew install findutils coreutils


kubectl get pods -o go-template -n gui2 --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}} {{.metadata.creationTimestamp}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | awk '$2 <= "'$(gdate -d '21 days ago' -Ins --utc | sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" { print $1 }' | gxargs --no-run-if-empty kubectl delete pod
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant of the answer by [dansl1982](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6415177/dansl1982) above that will delete all pods with a particular label in all namespaces.

```
kubectl get pods -A -l app=my-api -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.namespace}} {{.metadata.name}} {{.metadata.creationTimestamp}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | awk '$3 <= "'$(date -d'now-4 hours' -Ins --utc | sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" { print $1 " " $2 }' | xargs -L 1 --no-run-if-empty kubectl delete pod -n $1 $2
```

Answer (score 1):

No answer here by itself was complete for what I needed, so I took bits of (and upvoted) several answers, then mashed them together to delete completed pods older than a day, from various namespaces.

Here's what worked for me:

```bash
kubectl get pod --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase==Succeeded \
 | awk 'match($6,/[0-9]+d/) {print $1, $2}' \
 | xargs -L 1 --verbose --no-run-if-empty kubectl delete pod -n $1 $2
```

- `kubectl` to find for completed pods in all namespaces,
- `awk` to filter pods that finished a day or more ago (any age string ending with a `d`),
- `xargs` to run (and output) `kubectl delete` against each pod, specifying the pod's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer by showing the custom field when `get pods` and filter by the `.metadata.creationTimestamp`

```
kubectl delete pod -n foo $(kubectl get pods -n foo --field-selector=status.phase=Failed -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,AGE:.metadata.creationTimestamp --no-headers=true --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk '$2 <= "'$(gdate -d '10 days ago' -Ins | sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" { print $1 }')
```

Based on the above command `-o=custom-columns=NAME:` has been used for the custom columns.

Answer (score 0):

For Powershell users, this deletes all pods older than a day:

```bash
kubectl get pods -o json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
  $_.items | Where-Object {
    $timestamp = [System.DateTime]::ParseExact($_.metadata.creationTimestamp, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
    $timestamp -le [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-1)
  } | ForEach-Object {
    kubectl delete pod $_.metadata.name
  }
}
```