# kubernetes kill containers older than?

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I have some certificates that I use, custom from OpenSSL tool, and from cert-manager using Letsencrypt.

Now the certificates expires as we know - how do I kill off containers that are about to expire?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934491/kubernetes-how-to-delete-pods-based-on-age-creation-time.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one  But I was looking for some settings.