# how to delete all secrets of a specific type in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have the `kubectl` to delete 1 secret:

```
kubectl delete -n my_name_space secret secret_name
```

If I want to delete all secrets of type `my_type` how can I do that?

Also how can I add filter to delete secrets older than 3 days?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get secrets of a particular type, you can use `--field-selector`. Here, is an example:

```
kubectl get secret --all-namespaces --field-selector type=Opaque
```

For deleting resources older than x days, please check this thread.
[Kubernetes: How to delete PODs based on age/creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934491/kubernetes-how-to-delete-pods-based-on-age-creation-time)

Answer (score 0):

Hello to get secret with a specific type :

```sh
kubectl get secret --all-namespaces --field-selector type=Opaque
```

Also you can get secret older than XXX-date days , you can use this :

```sh
kubectl get secrets -o json | jq -r "[.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, startTime: .metadata.creationTimestamp | fromdate } | select(.startTime < (now | . - XXX-date ))]" | jq -r ".[].name"
```

Don't forget to replace XXX-date by the number of seconds.