# How to get failing Pods in a Namespace that are at least a day old

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I'm trying to make a Bash script that scales down all Deployments of failing Pods (i.e. Pods that have at least one Container in "Waiting" state) that are older than one day.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious `kubectl` command for getting all failing Pods. The solution [here](https://blog.cubieserver.de/2021/list-all-failed-pods-in-a-namespace-with-kubectl/) is a partial answer to finding failing Pods, but it won't find Pods with one failing Container and one or more healthy Containers.

The solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934491/kubernetes-how-to-delete-pods-based-on-age-creation-time) does address how to find Pods older than one day, but it does not filter for failing Pods.

How can I get all failing Pods in a Namespace that are at least one day old?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `-o go-template` option to specify which fields we want, then use `awk` to filter based on the timestamp field and the `.state.waiting.reason` field(s):

```bash
kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}} {{.metadata.creationTimestamp}} {{range .status.containerStatuses}}{{.state.waiting.reason}} {{end}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'\
                | awk -vFPAT='([^[:space:]]*)|(<[^<]+>)' \
                '$2 <= "'$(date -d 'yesterday' -Ins --utc| sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" \
                && ($3 != "<no value>" || ($4 != "<no value>" && $4 != "")) {print $1}'
```

The `awk -vFPAT='([^[:space:]]*)|(<[^<]+>)'` tells awk to interpret as a field anything that does not have a space in it, **or** anything that starts with a `<`, does not have another `<` in it, and ends in a `>`. This allows awk to correctly interpret Containers' `.state.waiting.reason` of `<no value>`.

The `'$2 <= "'$(date -d 'yesterday' -Ins --utc| sed 's/+0000/Z/')'"` is stolen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934491/kubernetes-how-to-delete-pods-based-on-age-creation-time) and tells awk to filter for creationTimestamps that are older than 24 hours.

The `($3 != "<no value>" || ($4 != "<no value>" && $4 != ""))` tells awk to filter for Pods where *either* the first Container's waiting status is not `<no value>` *or* the second Container's waiting status is neither `<no value>` nor empty. **Note** that this assumes each Pod in the cluster has a max of two Containers; we could easily add a `|| ($5 != "<no value>" && $5 != "")` if there could be three-Container Pods.

This command will capture all Pods older than 24 hours in the given Namespace that have at least one Container in CrashLoopBackOff, Init:ContainerStatusUnknown, or ImagePullBackOff - that is, at least one Container whose status is `waiting`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Check if the following returns the correct pods:

**Notice**:

- Status.phase value, for more values refer to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase).
- There are no easy ways within kubernetes thats why awk is used the
  first value right after match ($1) means one day old.

> kubectl get pods
> --field-selector=status.phase=Failed --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
> | awk 'match($1,/[6-9]d|[0-9][0-9]d|[0-9][0-9][0-9]d/) {print $0}'

**2.** Once confirmed first step run kubectl delete:

> kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pods
> --field-selector=status.phase=Failed --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($1,/[6-9]d|[0-9][0-9]d|[0-9][0-9][0-9]d/) {print $0}')

**In case you are not in the namespace set as default (where pods reside) just pass the namespace flag with name on both statements.**